# .NET to Java Tutorials

Tags: java, .net

I have been asked to create a simple database web app using Java. 
I'm a C# .net programmer and I haven't really created any Java web apps before.
Do you guys know of any good books/online tutorials that can help me catch up on how Java web apps work?

I got very little time to get up to speed, so any thorough examples will help a lot.

Comment: Did you find any good books/online tutorials that can help? Please consider sharing anything useful (or half useful) as it might help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this blog could help you out with some bases http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html and I actually like making web apps with spring, you can find more information and a step by step tutorial here http:// static.springframework.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step

And I know one book from Microsoft I think it's "From Java to C#" or "C# for Java developers" I can't remember the name of the book but it could probably help you too, unfortunately it is not an online book.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be written in Java, or only run on the JVM? In the latter case, by far the fastest and easiest way to get a simple DB/Web app running is [Grails](http://grails.org/), which is similar to Ruby on Rails and uses Groovy, a Java-derived dynamic language.

Comment: It has to be written in java. Others on my team are more familiar with java and i doubt that they would wanna use anything else.